# React Native Camera: After taking a picture, How to save it inside the app itself instead of saving it in gallery?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

This Question is related to `react-native-camera` library that I'm using in one of my projects.

```
<RNCamera
   ref={ref => {
      this.camera = ref;
   }}
   style = {styles.preview}
   type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
   flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
   permissionDialogTitle={'Permission to use camera'}
   permissionDialogMessage={'We need your permission to use your camera phone'}
/>
```

the above code saves the image in the gallery. How do we save it inside the app folder or some other private folder and not to show it inside the device gallery?

Comment: You should take a look at the `takePicture = async function()`, that function gives you full control over the taken picture https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks for the response. But I'm unable to find an option which enables you to select the destination path or to save it in a different location other than the gallery.

Comment: Looking at the function, `takePicture = async function()` that returns a `data.uri`...using other lib, like `react-native-fs` you can move the file to whichever location you want

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks again. Will try react-native-fs. But I believe there might be an option for react-native-camera to perform the desired action.

Comment: It looks like the the takePictureAsync() function takes an option called path.
Docs - path (file path on disk). Specifies the path on disk to save picture to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through [CameraRoll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#savetocameraroll)

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(tag, [type]);
```

> Saves the photo or video to the camera roll or photo library.
>
> On Android, the tag must be a local image or video URI, such as "file:///sdcard/img.png".
>
> On iOS, the tag can be any image URI (including local, remote asset-library and base64 data URIs) or a local video file URI (remote or data URIs are not supported for saving video at this time).
>
> If the tag has a file extension of .mov or .mp4, it will be inferred as a video. Otherwise it will be treated as a photo. To override the automatic choice, you can pass an optional type parameter that must be one of 'photo' or 'video'.
>
> Returns a Promise which will resolve with the new URI.

Comment: My question was how to not to save the images to the default camera roll path. I don't want the users to see the app images in their gallery. I guess your answer may not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

As per react native docs you should try this...

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
   first: 20,
   assetType: 'Photos',
})
.then(r => {
   this.setState({ photos: r.edges });
})
.catch((err) => {
  //Error Loading Images
});
```

[CameraRoll documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/cameraroll.html)

Comment: Can you explain what this piece of code does? My question was how to store the images in a different location other than camera roll on an iPhone? I might be wrong, But I don't see this answering my query.